# Правописание слов на -мый

Tags: орфография

Как пишутся краткие формы слов на -мый? Как отличить причастие на -мый от прилагательного?
Все его поступки не?объяснимы. Источник знаний не?истощим. Мороз был не?стерпим. Глубина чеховских произведений не?исчерпаема. Вещество не?растворимо в воде. Микроб не?видим. Наследство не?делимо на части. Впечатления не?забываемы. Поступок просто не?мыслим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реально только автор может сказать, прилагательное оно или причастие. По систематике отличие в том, что причастие определяет состояние (обычно - меняющееся), а прилагательное - качество: постоянное, не связанное с изменением внешних воздействий. Во многих случаях отличить очень сложно, не зная авторского замысла. Вот для этих-то случаев и придумано правило зависимых слов. Беда в том, что правило это не абсолютное.

Почти во всех ваши примерах скорее всего прилагательное, причем со слитным написанием, ибо речь идет именно о **качестве**, причем качестве новообразованном с помощью "не". Но и раздельное написание допустимо, если это соответствует мысли автора - или по контексту оно требуется.

Единственный пример, о котором надо сказать особо - "наследство не()делимо"  на части. Кратное прилагательное "делимо" крайне редко используется вне специальной литературы. Поэтому здесь возникает коллизия - с одной стороны есть нечто, что можно трактовать как зависимые слова (на части), с другой - неудачное без "не" слово "делимо". Логичный, на мой взгляд, выход вообще подобных сочетаний избегать, уточнение "на части" там совершенно лишнее. Но если уж никак нельзя без него обойтись, то написание должно быть слитным в юридическом документе (там есть термин "неделимое имущество") и по общим правилам, т. е. раздельно, в любом другом контексте.

Comment: Хорошо известно, что прилагательные обозначают качественный признак, а причастия признак процессуальный (признак как действие,  существующее во времени). Только эта истина не всегда практична в применении, поэтому по возможности для подобных задач ищут ФОРМАЛЬНОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ, в частности для написания НЕ со словами на МЫЙ. Хотя слова на МЫЙ  образуются с помощью суффиксов причастий ЕМ и ИМ,  большинство из них обозначают качественный признак и  являются прилагательными;  только небольшая их часть относится к страдательным причастиям настоящего времени.

Comment: Слова на  МЫЙ являются причастиями при соблюдении двух условий: причастие образовано от переходного глагола несовершенного вида; причастие имеет зависимое слово в Т.п., обозначающее производителя или орудие действия. А причем тут Т.п.? Дело в том, что именно Т.п. служит показателем ПРОЦЕССУАЛЬНОСТИ признака. Наличие зависимого слова в Т.п. со значением производителя действия подчеркивает РЕАЛЬНЫЙ ХАРАКТЕР  ДЕЙСТВИЯ: невидимый  в  тумане корабль, но: не видимый мной корабль.

Comment: Таким образом, из длинных рассуждений получается простое практическое решение  Частицу НЕ со словами на МЫЙ, как правило,  пишем слитно, а проверяем только «подозрительные» случаи.  Это усиление отрицания и наличие зависимого слова в Т.п. В этих случаях дополнительно проверяется употреблении слова без НЕ,  а также вид и переходность глагола при наличии  сущ.  форме Т.п.

Answer (score 3):

При отсутствии зависимых слов в Т.п. все формы на -мый являются прилагательными, поэтому во всех приведенных примерах  слитное  написание НЕ (нет зависимых слов или зависимые слова не в Т.п.).

Часть прилагательных не употребляется без НЕ (нестерпимый, неистощимый), это дополнительный признак для слитного написания.

Answer (score 1):

К прилагательным на -мый относятся слова, образованные от   н е п е р е х о д н ы х   глаголов (независимый) или от глаголов  с о в е р ш е н н о г о  вида (неисправимый). На эти слова распространяются общие правила написания не с прилагательными: они пишутся слитно и при наличии пояснительных слов, а также в краткой форме (остров необитаем).

Однако остается в силе правило раздельного написания прилагательных с не, если в качестве пояснительных слов выступают местоимения и наречия, начинающиеся с ни, или сочетания далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не (ни с чем не сравнимое впечатление)  Исключение составляют слова, которые без не не употребляются, например: никем непобедимая армия.

Следует    различать    написание   не    со    словами    на    -мый,   образованными   от п е р е х о д н ы х   глаголов   н е с о в е р ш е н н о г о   вида:   такие слова могут быть как страдательными причастиями настоящего времени, так и прилагательными (в первом случае написание с не раздельное, во втором – слитное).

а) Причастиями они являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется творительный падеж действующего лица, реже творительный орудия.

б) При наличии других пояснительных слов они становятся прилагательными. Не любимый матерью ребёнок – нелюбимые в детстве игры.

Comment: Похоже, что вы откуда-то скопировали текст целиком и в нём остались следы от прошлого форматирования, в частности точки от маркированных списков. Хорошо бы форматирование исправить, а также дать ссылку на источник.